# CSS Form Scroll / Overflow

Tags: html, css, forms, overflow

I have the following web page with a form. The HTML is shown below (other irrelevant HTML that is not relevant to the question has been removed). The problem is the form is not scrolling. Only certain elements are shown and the rest of the page will not scroll (I only want the form, which is form1, to be scrollable so I can see the rest of the form). I have set overflow: scroll but this hasn't made a difference. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
    <div id="mainwrapper">

        <div id="contentwrapper">

            <div id="content">     
 <div id="form1">

          <fieldset>
                        <legend>Account Information</legend>




                                           <div id="form1c">  Billing Address      </div>
                                       <div id="form1a">
                                       House/Flat number
                                       <br>Street
                                       <br>Town
                                       <br>Postcode
                                       <br> Country
                                    </div>

                                      <div id="form1c">  Payment Card Details   </div>
                                       <div id="form1a">
                                       Cardholder's Name
                                       <br>Type of card
                                       <br>Card Number
                                       <br>Start Date
                                       <br>End Date
                                       <br>CVN Number
                                    </div>

                                       <div id="form1c">  Payment Card Details </div>
                                       <div id="form1a">
                                       Cardholder's Name
                                       <br>Type of card
                                       <br>Card Number
                                       <br>Start Date
                                       <br>End Date
                                       <br>CVN Number
                                    </div>



                                    </div>

                                    <div id="editaddressbutton">
                                   <a href="editaddress.html">Edit</a>
                                   </div>

                                    <div id="editaddressbuttona">
                                   <a href="card.html">Edit</a>
                                   </div>


                                    </div>


                                </div>

                </div> 

  <div id="footer">
        Copyright  2016 | All Rights Reserved | Copyright | Disclaimer | Privacy Policy | Terms and Conditions of use

        </footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family: Sans-Serif;
            line-height: 1.5em;
                overflow: scroll;

        }

        #header {
            background: #8b0000;
            height: 40px;
        }


        #mainwrapper {
            overflow: scroll;
        }



        #content {

            height: 550px;
            overflow: scroll;

        }

#form1 {
        position: fixed;
left: 450px;
top: 200px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width:500px;
 margin-right: -15px;
overflow: scroll;
        }


            #form1a {
font-size: 70%;
overflow: scroll;
        }

        #form1c {
color: #8b0000;
overflow: scroll;
        }

 #footer{
            clear: left;
            width: 100%;
                background: #8b0000;
            height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 0;
            height: 40px;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size: 70%;

        }
```

Comment: remove `position:fixed` from `#form1` CSS

Comment: It has to be fixed to fit in with the rest of the page @freestock.tk

Comment: @Rich use `position:absolute` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try this:

Add some height to your form container.

```
#form1{height:400px;overflow-y:auto}
```

So that if the form contents are more than the height of the form then the form will scroll.